# Creating Multiple Instances of the Same Class

Tags: java, oop, opengl, collision-detection, multiple-instances

I have a question that's kind of hard to explain so i'll try to do my best..

I have the following code that creates two new blocks:

```
 Block block2 = new Block(new Location(30,30,30),false, 20, blockTexture2, blockTexture2, blockTexture2, blockTexture2, blockTexture2, blockTexture2, false);
      hittableCubes.add(block2);
       block2.draw();

       Block block = new Block(new Location(100,100,100),false, 20, blockTexture2, blockTexture2, blockTexture2, blockTexture2, blockTexture2, blockTexture2, false);
          hittableCubes.add(block);
       block.draw();
```

Then I have the following code to detect collision:

```
 public static boolean hitBlock(){
    int count = 0;

  for(Block block: hittableCubes){
     System.out.println(block.getLocation().getX() + " " + block.getLocation().getY() + " " + block.getLocation().getZ());
      if(-block.getLocation().getX()+block.getSize() >= camera.getX() && -block.getLocation().getX()-block.getSize() <= camera.getX()
              && -block.getLocation().getY()+block.getSize() >= camera.getY() && -block.getLocation().getY()-block.getSize() <= camera.getY()
              && -block.getLocation().getZ()+block.getSize() >= camera.getZ() && -block.getLocation().getZ()-block.getSize() <= camera.getZ()
              ){
          count++;

      }

      }
  if(count != 0){
      return true;
  }else{
      return false;
  }
}
```

the collision detection works for "block", but not "block2". The block2's location is actually at popping up at 130,130,130 not 100,100,100. When I create another block at 20,20,20, the new blocks location would be at 150,150,150, and block2 would be at 130,130,130. Any idea why this is happening?

This is my Block class:

```
package threeD;

public class Block {
    Texture textureFront;
    Texture textureBehind;
    Texture textureLeft;
    Texture textureRight;
    Texture textureBottom;
    Texture textureTop;
    float cubeSize;
     Location location;
    boolean debuggingMode = false;
    CameraMovement camera;

    /*
     * 
     * XY controls the spot the cube is located (XY,XY)
     * 
     * Z controls the size of the cube (Z,Z)
     * 
     */

    public Block(Location location, boolean hitable, float cubeSize,Texture textureFront, Texture textureBehind, Texture textureLeft, Texture textureRight, Texture textureBottom, Texture textureTop, boolean debuggingMode){
        this.textureFront = textureFront;
        this.textureBehind = textureBehind;
        this.textureLeft = textureLeft;
        this.textureRight = textureRight;
        this.textureBottom = textureBottom;
        this.textureTop = textureTop;
        this.location = location;

        this.cubeSize = cubeSize;

    }




    public  void setSize(float size){
        cubeSize = size;
    }
    public Location getLocation(){
        return location;
    }
    public float getSize(){
        return cubeSize;
    }


    public void setFrontTexture(Texture texture){
        textureFront = texture;
    }

    public void setBehindTexture(Texture texture){
        textureBehind = texture;
    }

    public void setLeftTexture(Texture texture){
        textureLeft = texture;
    }

    public void setRightTexture(Texture texture){
        textureRight = texture;
    }

    public void setBottomTexture(Texture texture){
        textureBottom = texture;
    }

    public void setTopTexture(Texture texture){
        textureTop = texture;
    }



    public void debuggingMode(boolean debug){
        debuggingMode = debug;
    }


    public void draw(){



        glTranslatef(location.getX(), location.getY(), location.getZ()); 


        //draws the block with a lot of code(not relevant to my question)
    }

}
```

Here is my Location class:

```
    package threeD;

public class Location {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

     public Location(float f, float g, float h){
         this.x = f;
         this.y = g;
         this.z = h;
     }

     public float getX(){
         return x;
     }
     public float getZ(){
         return z;
     }
     public float getY(){
         return y;
     }
     public void setX(float x){
         this.x = x;
     }
     public void setY(float y){
         this.y = y;
     }
     public void setZ(float z){
         this.z = z;
     }
     public void setLocation(float x, float y, float z){
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         this.z = z;
     }
     public void translate(float x, float y, float z){
         this.x += x;
         this.y += y;
         this.z += z;
     }
}
```

The collision detection is correct, however. it's at the location 100,100,100 but the block is not.

Comment: Why do you create one block, which is drawn, and put a completely new instance in 'hittableCounts' container?

Comment: Sorry had that left over from debugging, I'll fix that.

Comment: Please, add source code for the Location class.

Comment: Added my Location class, sorry again

Comment: Maybe add breakpoints into methods in Location that may change its internal values (setX/Y/Z, setLocatiom, translate) and debug it again? It seems that the internal state of location is changed.

Comment: I was thinking the location is changing due to calling the Block class wrong, since it works fine with one block but not the second. I'll try it out though

Comment: When I print out the location for the block I hit, it prints out the correct block and location. So the values don't change. Maybe it has something to do with my collision detection statement?

Comment: "The block2's location is actually at popping up at 130,130,130 not 100,100,100."
So I guess that now it is printing the values 100,100,100?

Comment: correct, but it's actually at 130, 130, 130

Comment: Regarding your collision detection - if x is is the middle point of a block, then you add a half of block size:

    (block.getLocation().getX()-block.getSize()/2) >= camera.getX() && (block.getLocation().getX()+block.getSize()/2) <= camera.getX()

Comment: Actually the size is half of the block, but thanks for pointing that out I'll change that. But that still wouldn't fix my problem unfortunately

Comment: Wait. You create block at location (100,100,100), it's printing this values, so where do you find the values (130,130,130)?

Comment: Because I created a cube for a arena type thing, and the top courner is at 100,100,100 and thats where the collision detection thinks the block is, and the actual block is 130,130,130 because when I change the collision detection to 30 more xyz, it works. But I can't keep changing it for each block. Visual: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8herdgv6xb3q6fq/Screenshot%202014-03-15%2019.19.37.png Also when I draw the first block at 100,100,100, it's below the second one

Comment: When I create a third block at 100,100,100, it works but the collision doesnt

Comment: Turns out I didn't use glPush/glPopMatrix...Funny because that's the only part of code I left out to make it better to read. Anyway thanks for the help